# In Parse, can I force related ParseObjects to get fetched?

Tags: android, caching, fetch, parse-platform

In the [Parse android docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers) it says that by default, related `ParsePbject`s are not fetched, implying that there is a setting that will fetch them. It later says that they cannot be fetched without a call to fetchIfNeeded. Which is it? I definitely need to fetch the related `ParseObject` and would prefer to do so without having to make multiple requests. Is that possible?

`By default, when fetching an object, related ParseObjects are not fetched. These objects' values cannot be retrieved until they have been fetched like so:`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the ParseQuery you are using to get the original object, you can use the include(key) method to tell it to also fetch the related object. This works for pointers and arrays of pointers.

Comment: Urgh, the Parse docs really should make this clearer - I just wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: Hence that include just works for pointers and not multiple Relational Objects

Answer (score -4):

No They Can't. I am also facing the similar problem. SO if you have two table and one table is having reference key from second table, then there is no such query where we can find relative data.

Its Sad. I wonder why they don't provide such a useful thing.